# How to manipulate the data pointed by a cursor before render it

Tags: meteor

everybody.

I have a doubt in this portion of my system: I want to encrypt some messages from users to the database and decrypt them when showing back to the users (that's just for privacy reasons). Since I couldn't find any native encrypt/decrypt library or even a better solution, then I am using the "crypto-js" (https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/), and it's working well so far. The problem is: when the user write a message I encrypt it and save it at the database. But when I retrieve that message from the database using the "find" method in a Template Helper (using the reactive computation idea to approach the desired "Live HTML"), what I get is just a cursor that will be used to render the message in my HTML. As you can see, the message is shown without be decrypted.
I was thinking in "fetch" the data from the cursor, run the decrypt function in a "for loop" over all messages, but that's too inefficient.
I was wondering if someone know how may I manipulate the data from the cursor before it be render, then I'll be able to decrypt each message on the fly.

Really thanks for your attention and sorry any bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a talk at the #meteor IRC channel and some ideas came out. And I thought that this one is the best solution for my case:

```
{{#each messages}}
    {{decrypt}}
{{/each}}
```

As helpers get the data from the context, the helper "decrypt" got the actual "message" in the loop as a "this" object. Then, I did the decryption and returned the message in plain text.
It works pretty well, further it is called reactively and make use of the cursor (that is update dynamically if data changes during the exhibition).

Thanks everybody whom helped me.

Comment: if you are calling decrypt on the client side, aren't you actually exposing your decyption key o the public as well?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a transform function. The transform is passed as the cursor is used so it only runs on each document as it is used:

```
YourCollection.find({}, {transform:function(doc) {

    var encrypted = doc.field1;
    doc.field1 = decrypt(encrypted)

    return doc;

});
```

So now each `field1` would be decrypted (on the web browser). Just before it was used. If you use `.fetch()` you would get all the decrypted data too.

Comment: Thanks, @Akshat! Your solution works well! One bad thing about it is that the method "transform" is not called reactively and that means not dynamically changes in my system :/
But that's a good solution and it works in certain way. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean, it sort of sits in the middle so if there is a reactive change it also gets re-run with the new changes, so it should change reactively too. Do you have a code snippet of how you're using it?

Comment: Hi, @Akshat! Well, I really do not know how this reactive call works deeply, but I just said that because I read this in the documentation website:
"transform functions are not called reactively. If you want to add a dynamically changing attribute to an object, do it with a function that computes the value at the time it's called, not by computing the attribute at transform time."
Then I think that maybe there is some sort of mechanism which prevents the data to pass through the "transform" function in a reactive call. Maybe... but I really don't know. But really thank you!

Comment: @jhow Yes this is true! But it won't apply to you because you're not using reactive attributes, i.e referenced from another collection. So if you change the content of the transform (that would be different without the transform), the output would also change- Which for decrypting the data looks like how you're using it

Answer (score 1):

You didn't posted the related code here, but I assume you have done something like this:

```
Template.yourTemplate.yourHelper = function(){
    return yourCollection.find({});
}
```

The thing is your are returning the data to the helper, in form of cursor, which is perfectly acceptable in general. But as you are storing encrypted messages in collection, each message is rendered as it is without performing decryption.

So, try to fetch an array instead of cursor using [`find().fetch()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#fetch) which gives the array equivalent of your cursor. Something like :

```
Template.yourTemplate.yourHelper = function(){
      var msg_arr = yourCollection.find({}).fetch(); // gives array instead of cursor.

      msg_arr.forEach( function( msg ){ 
         // traverse through each element of array and
         // perform decryption.
      });
}
```

Comment: Hey, @sohel khalifa, thanks for your attention! I noticed your observation as I said in my question and I am pretty sure that it may works well. The bad thing is about performance. I am worried about this "for loop" in a reactively method... :/
But I liked it, and if I don't find out a better way, I'll use it for sure. Thanks again!